# EOF marker when generating text files?

Tags: .net, ascii, text-files

When I'm generating a text file programatically, should I insert the ASCII EOF marker (decimal value 26) at the end of the file?

Do the .NET Programming Languages do this automatically?

Comment: 26 is not EOF. It's the Microsoft treat it as end of file. See http://www.asciitable.com/ , the real EOF should use 4

Comment: It's a moot point, but 4 isn't really EOF either.  It's "End Of Transmission".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no reason for the `^Z` `EOF` marker anymore (and there hasn't been for a long time) - it's a hold over from CP/M which did not support exact lengths for file sizes in the directory - file sizes were in terms of the number of 128 byte blocks, so to end a file on a non-128 byte boundary you had to use an EOF character.

Since early versions of MS-DOS were heavily influenced by CP/M (and Microsoft wanted CP/M programs to port easily), the convention stuck.

Your program should open text files with the appropriate attributes so the OS and/or language runtime will signal an EOF when it sees a `^Z` in case you come across a file that uses the convention.  But there's no need to write one anymore.

One possible exception is if you have a binary file, but want to put some text at the start of it, then a `^Z`, then your data. If someone dumps it to the console it'll say something intelligent instead of spewing garbage. There's not a whole lot of reason to do this, but I've seen that done rarely.

From Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP/M):

> File size was specified as the number
>   of 128-byte records (directly
>   corresponding to disk sectors on
>   8-inch drives) occupied by a file on
>   the disk. There was no generally
>   supported way of specifying byte-exact
>   file sizes. The current size of a file
>   was maintained in the file's file
>   control block (FCB) by the operating
>   system. Since many application
>   programs (such as text editors) prefer
>   to deal with files as sequences of
>   characters rather than as sequences of
>   records, by convention text files were
>   terminated with a control-Z character
>   (ASCII SUB, hexadecimal 1A).
>   Determining the end of a text file
>   therefore involved examining the last
>   record of the file to locate the
>   terminating control-Z. This also meant
>   that inserting a control-Z character
>   into the middle of a file usually had
>   the effect of truncating the text
>   contents of the file.

Answer (score 5):

No.  The EOF is produced by the OS's IO functions when reading the file.  It should not be stored in the file in modern systems.